# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

What is the easiest way to get rid of this simple error:

> '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'.

Some of the articles look really complex to solve this, but in my opinion, there should be an easy fix. Like putting `currentTime==(str(currentTime)).` Other things I attempted are at the bottom. My code :

```
df=pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None)    
last3Rows=df.iloc[-3:]    
for i in range(3):
    lastRow = df.iloc[i]
    tradeTime=lastRow[4]

    currentTime=datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    print (currentTime)
    print(type(currentTime))
    print (tradeTime)
    print(type(tradeTime))

    if currentTime > tradeTime:
        print("inner loop reached")
```

What I tried:

```
currentTime = datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Gives :

> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

```
currentTime = strptime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Gives :

> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

```
currentTime=datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

Gives :

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'

Comment: `tradeTime` is a `str`. You need to convert it to a `float`.

Comment: @flakes ...or, better, convert tradeTime to datetime (with `pd.to_datetime()`) and compare it directly with `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: I Think I see the real issue. I need to get rid of the colons in '15:45:05' to become 154505 so I can switch it to a float.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is the result of attempting to use the ">" operator with operands of different types. Thus, the easiest way to solve this is to convert them both to a type that has a valid greater-than operator implementation, like using the unix timestamp to cast to a float.

```
if float(currentTime.total_seconds()) > float(tradeTime.total_seconds()):
    print("inner loop reached")
```

Comment: i agree with your code. However, i get the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15:45:05'. I will have to get rid the of the colons, probably.

Comment: times should be handled as datetime objects or unix timestamps.